# Is there any meaning, which I am supposed to untangle, to things I saw during meditation?

Tags: meditation-insight

I had a friend who introduced me to Buddhism. He was very insistent I go to Buddhist groups, though I ended up going to a different one to the one he suggested (the leader was Theravāda not Mahāyāna). I haven't spoken to him in a long time, but he is the person I associate most strongly with Buddhism. He was very insistent that I chant the same mantras as him, and go to the groups he suggested.

In any case, during the meditation (which took place immediately after the one where I resolved to check if the universe is eternal) I saw these things:

1. I remembered a dream I had two days ago in which my Buddhist friend had changed from how I knew him. He was usually friendly and cheery, if a little unusual in manner sometimes. However, in the dream he looked very different and was angry, seemingly not just with me, but with everyone, but with me also. He grabbed me by my collar and screamed at me and I was afraid.
2. I saw there was a world within my laptop, which became large and over-filled with information, then shrunk to become the size of my left foot, and hovered just below my knee.
3. I saw a bright light, which was powerful and pure white, but tinged at the edges with gold. The light appeared to come from a figure, whom I saw as bound but then released from his bondage, stepping down from the place where he was bound to walk on the earth and talk to the people there.

Is it possible there is any meaning to these, which I am supposed to untangle? They seem to all be connected to my previous question, about the limits of the universe and the cycle of birth and death.

Comment: Was the group a legitimate, official Buddhist group? Did they demand donations or made an untrustworthy impression?

Comment: @OidaOudenEidos Yes. They wanted donations from my friend, and said that he needed to buy different items for his practice often.

Comment: Closing this question due to the the acceptance of satisfactory answer by the questioner, since it was flagged as an opinion based question.

Comment: @BuddhaTheis Sounds like this was some kind of sect, but not a Buddhist group, where you donate only if you want to (dana). If you want to get into real Buddhism, you could start by listening to this talk by Ajahn Sumedho https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LNb5fe_ixvg

Comment: @OidaOudenEidos Ok. I am helping some people in the English Language group edit their posts at the moment and they are showing me what I am doing wrong but I will look afterwards, I promise.

Comment: @BonnieTopits If a question is answered/answerable then it needn't be closed. The OP's "accepting" an answer is a signal that he or she is satisfied and doesn't need further answers (but the question isn't closed so people can add further answers if they want to anyway). This site (Buddhism.SE) is a bit more lenient than other SE sites about not closing answers ... see [Moderation policies for Questions](http://meta.buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/1558/254) which is specific to this site

Comment: ... see also  [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) and [Help Center > Asking](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help/asking) which are the general (not site-specific) help topics, which describe how the web site software works.

Comment: I am still learning, and will follow your advise. I remember reading that one should leave a comment on why one was voting to close, but I did not consult the help section at that time. It popped upon review asking for a vote on closed status.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to possibly determine the meaning of your thoughts, you would need to consult a psychoanalyst. What is important within the reference of a forum answering questions on Buddhism, is that these conceptual thoughts during meditation are to be pushed aside so that you return to your focal point, usually the breathe. The goal of meditation is not to allow your thoughts to jump from one to another while you sit on a cushion. The goal is the absence of thought, thereby generating a clear calm mind. This takes practice. As you are someone new to to Buddhism, I recommend that you not rely on your friend alone, but read and study, and attend as many teachings offered by genuine lamas in order to extend your knowledge. You have made a good start. The Buddha said to listen to what he had to say but explore the truth of it on one's own.